# TWRP boot loop on Z00T

Tags: boot-loop, twrp, lineageos

The last LineageOS OTA caused a TWRP boot loop.
I can get to fastboot with the volume keys.
I can use `./adb shell` briefly before reboot.

```
./fastboot erase cache
./fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.1.1-0-Z00T.img
```

did not resolve the issue.
What can be done to get this device booted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt install android-sdk-platform-tools-common fastboot
fastboot continue
```

Got me back to LineageOS.

It also seems to have fixed TWRP.